# Create input select image URL?

Tags: functions, media, input

My code in functions is:

```
<input type="text" name="Cat_meta[img]" id="Cat_meta[img]" size="3" style="width:60%;" value=" <?php echo $cat_meta['img'] ? $cat_meta['img'] : ''; ?>">
```

How to get select url as post add media

[image]

Comment: May be this link will help you in this. [link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-upload-media-library-widgets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Javascript you can pop-up the media and on select you can update the image URL to the textbox. Below is the code.

```
var custom_uploader;
jQuery('<Should-be-a-button-selector>').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        jQuery('#Cat_meta[img]').val(attachment.url);


    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
});
```

Comment: im add `<input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />` and edit `jQuery('upload_image_button').click(function(e) {` but not run give me full code. my scientific not good

Comment: `jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function(e) {`

Comment: You are using a class without class indicator `(.)`. That's the fault.

Comment: Have you enqueued the editor files ?